# Running rails action when anyone visits a certain page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i execute an controller action when anyone visits a certain page like the home page of my site

Thanks

Comment: Have you even tried to learn a single thing about Ruby on Rails before asking this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:** I agree with Logan Serman

**Second:** I'll try to explain, not sure if I can do this properly:

By visiting a page in rails app a controller action is executed already, from that action you make calls to another if you need. For exemple:

root path of your app:

```
root: 'pages#home'
```

means for home page it will call action `home` from `pages_controller`:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

def home
end

end
```

this already answers your question: *how can I call a controller action in home page?*

but let's say you have `another_action` in the same `controller` and you want to call that in your `home page`, you'll do:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    another_action
  end

  def another_action
  end

end
```

this way when home page will be opened, the `home` action will be executed and `another_action` too.